# How to use hCaptcha without a form in Vue3

Tags: vuejs3, hcaptcha

I'm trying to implement hCaptcha within a basic Vue3 app.

I have a login component with a "login" button. When it's clicked I call `Axios.Post()` if the response is successful I am emitting a `LoggedIn` message. The consumer of that component's `LoggedIn` message than hides the login component and shows the rest of the page/components.

Since I'm not using a form, I can't get the `h-captcha-response`. Is there another way to accomplish this?